# Why does using css break tabset in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, css, r-markdown

I have found that if I specify the css for a section then it breaks the `{.tabset}` for that section of the document. Please see the bellow example.

Is there any way to stop this?

```
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

<style type="text/css">
.mycontent{
}
</style>

# R Markdown

Some text

# Sets of working tabs {.tabset}
## Tab 1
## Tab 2

#
<div class="mycontent">
# Sets of broken tabs {.tabset}
## Tab 1
## Tab 2
</div>
```

The document:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom specific sections with CSS chunk by adding ids or classes to section header, see [3.1.4.1 Custom CSS](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html). Obviously, you can ignore the CSS style applied below.

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{css my-content, echo = FALSE}
.mycontent{
  float: right;
  color: blue;
}
```

# R Markdown

Some text

# Sets of working tabs {.tabset}
## Tab 1
## Tab 2

# Sets of broken tabs {.tabset .mycontent}
## Tab 1
## Tab 2
````

[image]

Comment: is there any way to apply that to the majority of my document, except the header?

Comment: Try adding global style `body { color: lightblue; }` to CSS chunk.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for width, I added `body { max-width: 940px !important; }` to my code and it altered the width of the header in addition to the body.

Comment: Hi, I believe you are looking to style `.main-container { max-width: 940px; }` . Try increasing/decreasing the value of `px` to see a difference. The `.body {}` selector is above the `.main-container {}`. See [A CSS Crash Course](https://rstudio4edu.github.io/rstudio4edu-book/css-crash.html) for how to _Inspect_ your (or any) webpage.